# onFinderCategoryChangeState event for com_finder in Joomla never fires

Tags: plugin, smartsearch, plugin-events

I am implementing a plugin for jdownloads to be used in the component smart search. To implement this plugin I have to use the event onFinderCategoryChangeState to actualize the state to the download flies when the state of the categories of them change state. This event should be fired when the state of the category of the downloads change in the list of categories. I put a throw exception in this event function but this exception is never throw when I change a state of a category.

Here is my code in the plugin:

```
public function onFinderCategoryChangeState($extension, $pks, $value) {
    throw new Exception('extension --> ' . $extension);

    if ($extension == 'com_jdownloads') {
        $this->categoryStateChange($pks, $value):
    }
}
```

In the others plugins for the smart search there is this comment in the onFinderCategoryChangeState function:

> Method to update the item link information when the item category is
>   changed. This is fired when the item category is published or
>   unplublished from the list view.

Why in my case the event doesn't fire?

Comment: It´s related to the plugin order? Maybe you have to put your plugin after the one called "Content - Smart Search"?

Comment: @miguelbgouveia can you confirm that you are extending the FinderIndexerAdapter class? Also, have you setup all of the public properties ($content, $extension, $layout, $type_title, $table, $state_field ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called "Content - Smart Search" element finder in group content that triggers this event. In my installation this plugin was unpublished. It must be published for the onFinderCategoryChangeState to fire.

Confusingly there is also a plugin called "Smart Search - Content", element content in group finder.

Are you sure that the "Content - Smart Search" - plugin is published?

Comment: Yes @jonasfh I have the "Content - Smart Search" element finder published. If it was unpublished it will not generate any index words.The problem should be other.